# Combining multiple Java classes with ASM at runtime

Tags: java, class, java-bytecode-asm

I'd like to merge several java classes into one. I've read ASM documentation and this http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/merging_class_methods_with_asm but I can't understand how I can achieve my goal.

Are there more detailed examples about this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the way you want to merge two classes together?  It will merge two methods by adding the code together when this might not make any sense.  Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to integrate several data types in one to manage only one type.

Comment: How would combining them at runtime reduce your management overhead?  You would still have multiple source files, except now you have an unsupported deployment methodology. How would you debug such a program?

Comment: Along Peter Lawrey's train of thought, wouldn't it be easier to write a wrapper class that references the other types and provides accessor methods that combines their data in they ways you need?

Comment: I will use annotations to organize the new class structure and with a policy to sort the different behaviors.

Comment: My problem is that i won't know the different structure and I would like to generate this wrapper dynamically.

Comment: @Sergio This doesn't sound like a right solution for a problem. Perhaps you should state the original problem first to understand what you are trying to achieve with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

from java 1.5 there is a feature called instrumentation which enable you to manipulate byte code of a program during runtime. In addition, you can also manipulate byte code while the class loader loads specific class to the JVM memory. the ASM framework provide you tools to manipulate byte code easily by converting byte code assembler to something readable and adding some utilities to simplify your work. notice that manipulating byte code is very advance technique and you really need to know about the JVM and byte code before doing it.
I personally suggest you will do the ideas that appear above. but if you still presist doing it i suggest you read about instrumentation here: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html
and than deep dive to ASM or javaassist framework: http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.co.il/2008/07/java-instrumentation.html
i think java assist is easier to i suggest working with that.
i hoped i help